# Android Volley : comes with a .gitignore

Tags: android, github, android-volley, gitignore

I have just uploaded my Android Project to my github repo and noticed that the volley folder is greyed out and can't be accessed.

So I took a closer look at my volley folder, inside my MyApplication folder and noticed a `.gitignore` file in it. Funny thing tho I didn't create the file. Is there a reason for this? Shouldn't I get rid of this file and upload my volley folder?

If someone downloads my Project and tries to run it, Android Studio will probably look for a volley folder that just isn't there?.. Am I missing something or ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.gitignore is automatically included in volley project when you clone(or download) it from AOSP repository. Here is the content of .gitignore you originally face to:

> bin
>
> gen
>
> .gradle
>
> build
>
> .settings
>
> target
>
> *.iml
>
> .idea
>
> local.properties

As you can see in the volley repository, there are no files or folders listed above. Therefore, you have not included none of the items in your project except **src** folder that you have compiled it in your project. So, don't worry. Nothing wrong would happen with it.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

.gitignore is created automatically when you create a repo for a project. You should put inside it the path to files that you don't want to be uploaded to git, basically files that must be ignored like a database file.

Comment: I do understand the concept behind the `.gitignore` files, but as I have already said, I did NOT create the `.gitignore` inside the volley folder. It just came with it - so my question still remains - why? and should I remove it to upload the volley folder?